# Channel Images: "success":"no","body":"No file was uploaded or file is not allowed by EE.(See EE Mime-type settings)."}

Tags: channel-images

I am getting a error every time I try and upload an image using channel images.

There's no file size or dimension restrictions in upload preferences, its a simple .jpg about 50kb. Max upload is set to 8mb. tried .png too.

Error: "success":"no","body":"No file was uploaded or file is not allowed by EE.(See EE Mime-type settings)."}

ExpressionEngine 2.9
Channel Images 5.4.19

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted that entry and published the page again. (it was in a home channel, so only one entry luckily.)

Answer (score 0):

Is this happening locally or on a host?  Can you upload that file via the EE File manager?  When I got a similar error (for a larger file) using Channel Images, the fix was to tweak my settings.  Here is what I am using:

```
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 256M
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 200M
```

or via .htaccess (if your host allows)

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value max_execution_time 600
php_value max_input_time 600
php_value memory_limit 256M
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I have already tried those in php.ini. It's on a server, I can upload them via the file manager. No matter what file with any file size it won't upload. I have also created a new channel image field in the same field group with the same results. Even if I change the upload location. Only in this channel/field group though. I have channel images fields in other field groups that work fine.

Comment: This is by no means resolved, the reason behind this issue was never found. But to get around it I deleted that entry and published the page again. (it was in a home channel, so only one entry luckily.)

Not sure if I can mark this as answered??

Comment: So after you deleted the entry, you were able to create a new entry and the upload worked?  If so, I would add a new answer with what worked, then you can accept it as the correct one.